# Chilkat How to start SSH with parameter for Bash Terminal

Tags: c#, automation, chilkat

I am trying to connect to an SSH terminal with the following option.

```
ssh -t root@IP "bash -l"
```

I can do it in PuTTy manuall this way:
[image]

This is how I am connecting with C#:

```
sshChannel = sshClient.OpenSessionChannel();

if (sshClient.SendReqPty(sshChannel, "dumb", 1000, 100000, 0, 0))
{

}
```

I cannot find in the documentation how to do this. Does anyone have an idea?
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csSshRef.html